# Error in Google plus sign in from android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working on sign in through google plus in my project.But the problem I am facing here is after clicking the google plus sign in button.it asks me to select the google plus account from the list of device accounts and after selecting the button nothing is happening.I have to again press the google plus button to call the `OnConnected()` method.But I want `OnConnected()` to be called on the first click of the button after selecting the google account.Please help.

```
Here is my code for my complete java class:



    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    TextView Fpassword, Signup;
    EditText email, password;
    ImageView Signin, fb_button, gplus_button;
    LogInActivity myContext;
    static String personName;
    static int requestcode;
    Validation validation;
    String LOG_TAG="ani";
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private CallbackManager callbackmanager;
    //for G+
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 50;
    static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE)).build();
        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        myContext = (LogInActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        Fpassword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ForgotPassword);
        Signup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SignUp);
        email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Email_Val);
        password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.PasswordVal);
        Signin = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.signin);
        fb_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.FB_btn);
        //facebook and google connection manager initialisation..
        gplus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Gplus_btn);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Fpassword.setPaintFlags(Fpassword.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        Signup.setPaintFlags(Signup.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        email.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#727272"));
        password.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#727272"));
        Fpassword.setOnClickListener(this);
        Signup.setOnClickListener(this);
        Signin.setOnClickListener(this);
        fb_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        gplus_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        validation = new Validation();
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.ForgotPassword)
        {
            Fragment forgotpassword = new ForgotPasswordFragment();
            myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_login, forgotpassword).addToBackStack("fragBack1").commit();

        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.SignUp)
        {
            Fragment signup = new SignUpFragment();
            myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_login, signup).addToBackStack("fragBack1").commit();

        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.signin)
        {


            if (!validation.isValidEmail(email.getText().toString())) {

                email.setError("please enter a Valid Email Address");
            }

            if (!validation.isValidPassword(password.getText().toString())) {

                password.setError("min password length has to be 6");
            }

            if (validation.isValidEmail(email.getText().toString()) && validation.isValidPassword(password.getText().toString()))
            {
                if (Network.isNetworkAvailable(myContext))
                {
                    signInVolley();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(myContext, "no internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.FB_btn)
        {
            if (Network.isNetworkAvailable(myContext))
            {//Intent intent_signin = new Intent(myContext, HomeActivity.class);
                // startActivity(intent_signin);
                Fblogin();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(myContext,"no internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.Gplus_btn)
        {

            if(Network.isNetworkAvailable(myContext)) {
                //Intent intent_signin = new Intent(myContext, HomeActivity.class);
                // startActivity(intent_signin);
                onSignInClicked();
                Log.d("ajflow","onclick");

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(myContext,"no internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

    }

    private void onSignInClicked() {
        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.

        mShouldResolve = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d("ajflow", "onsignin click");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("ajflow", "onStart");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }
    private void Fblogin()
    {


        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday,user_friends"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                Log.d("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                Log.d("LoginActivity", object.toString());
                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(object);
                                System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);
                                String str_firstname = null, str_id = null;
                                String responseValue = response.toString();
                                responseValue = responseValue.replace("Response:  responseCode: 200,", "");
                                Log.d("animeshnew", responseValue);


                                try {
                                    str_firstname = object.getString("name");
                                    str_id = object.getString("id");
                                    String str_email = object.getString("email");
                                    Intent login = new Intent(myContext, HomeActivity.class);
                                    String urlValue = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + str_id + "/picture?width=" + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE + "&height=" + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                                    SharedPref.Create_SharePref(myContext, str_firstname, urlValue);
                                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                    startActivity(login);
                                    myContext.finish();


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.d("animesh123", "aa");
                                }


                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,picture");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
                Toast.makeText(myContext, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    //to check if the fb user is logged in or not
    public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
        Log.d("ajflow","onconnected");
        getProfileInfo();


    }
    public void getProfileInfo()
    {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null)
        {
            Log.d("ajflow", "profileinfo");
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String id=currentPerson.getId();
            String birthDate=currentPerson.getAboutMe();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.d("sachin", "Name: " + personName + " " + currentPerson.getName() + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ",BirthDay:" + birthDate + ",Id :"+id+", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            Intent login=new Intent(myContext,HomeActivity.class);
            SharedPref.Create_SharePref(myContext,personName, personPhotoUrl);
            signOutFromGplus();
            startActivity(login);
            myContext.finish();


        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(myContext,"Problem in connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }





    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(callbackmanager!=null){
            callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        }
        Log.d("ani", "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);
        Log.d("ajflow","onactivityresult");

          if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
            if (resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }

            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
        Log.d("ajflow","onconnectionfailed");
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d("ani", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve)
        {
            Log.d("ajflow","both false true");
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
                try {
                        Log.d("ajflow","has resolution");

                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
                    Log.d("ajflow", "try over");
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e("ani", "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    Log.d("ajflow","in catch");

                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                }
            }
        }


    }
    /**
     * Sign-out from google
     * */
    static void signOutFromGplus() {
        Log.d("ajflow","signout");
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();



        }

    }

    public  void signInVolley()
    {
        mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .getRequestQueue();
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {

            params.put("email_id", email.getText().toString());
            params.put("password",password.getText().toString());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest=new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ApiClass.SignIn_URL,params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("aniloginsignin", response + "");
                try {

                    String successValue=response.getString("success");
                    Log.d("anisuccess",successValue);
                    Log.d("anilogin",successValue);
                    if(successValue.equals("1"))
                    {
                        JSONObject data=response.getJSONObject("data");
                        String name=data.getString("user_name");
                        Log.d("aniloginname",name);
                        Intent login = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                        SharedPref.Create_SharePref(getActivity(), name, "");
                        startActivity(login);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                    else if(successValue.equals("0"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myContext,"Invalid Email ID or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
    }


}
```

Comment: there is problem in key of your google plus account

Comment: @bpA:-error in key does not allow any connection.right?but here I am getting connection after second click anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for onConnectionFailed:

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
Log.e(LOG_TAG, connectionResult.toString());
            //If connectionResult does not have resolution
            if(!connectionResult.hasResolution()){
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(connectionResult.getErrorCode())){
                    Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, errorcode, REQUEST_CONSENT);
            dialog.show();
                    return;
                }

            }
            if(!mIsResolving ){
                    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
                    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
                    // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting to Resolve Failed Connection");
                    mIsResolving = true;
                    try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception while starting Resolution Activity: "+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
```

In your onActivityResult, get result:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH){
            mIsResolving = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if (mGoogleApiClient != null && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Result Code not OK");
            }
        }else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Request Code didn't match");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Namrata--Still I have to click twice for the login.By the way I am getting an error in the log cat as seen below.

E/ani﹕ ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{3071f27f: android.os.BinderProxy@25a1224c}}


and a log state ment too

 D/ani﹕ Attempting to Resolve Failed Connection

Comment: Check edited answer : In onActvityResult, make mIsResolving = false rather than authInProgress = false

Comment: @Namrata-still same same thing.same error messages too

Comment: I hope you are removing this variable: mShouldResolve. And try to debug, your flow should be like this: SignInButton Clicked --> onSignInClicked() -->In onConnectionFailed, if(!connectionResult.hasResolution()) will be called asking to choose account --> onActivityResult, it will try to connect again --> In OnConnectionFailed, if(!mIsResolving) will be called now asking to give permissions  that your app will be accessing, Accept those permissions --> onConnected will be called. Also clear data of your app and uninstall it. Try to debug with fresh install.

Comment: @namrata-yes,from Logcat messages I got the flow.on first click on signin click onclick ﹕ onconnectionfailed then while again clicking:-- onsignin click onclick onconnected profileinfo flow is like this.So i guess flow is interrupted some where in onconnectionfailed on the first click.Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Please don't click twice on signin button.(For first time)Let it go to onConnectionFailed and wait for a while, don't click signin button the moment you get into onConnectionFailed. If you have correctly followed my code, onConnectionFailed have workarounds for dealing with failure while connecting for the first time and ultimately googleApiclient.connect() will be called again from onActivityResult and accept those permissions dialog will be presented to user and it will be connected.

Comment: @Namrata--first of all nothing is happening after waiting and no permission screen is also appearing

Comment: Kindly edit your question with your current code so that I at my end can find out the root cause after running on my machine.

Comment: @Namrata--onActivityResult() is not even been triggered

Comment: @Namrata--Hey thank you,I solved it,I did not called the onActivityResult() in base Activity..:)

Comment: Sorry I was a bit busy but that's great you could solve it. If you feel my answer has helped you, please upvote it.